# change query based on textbox change using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've been trying to change a query using php with ajax. Here's how it goes

1. I have a dropdown that when changed it will then copy the selected data to a textbox which I achieved using javascript like so.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#animaloption").change(function () {
          $('#animalfilter').val($("#animaloption").val());
        });
   });
   ```

And then

2. I need to check if input textbox with id of **animalfilter** is changed and then query it using ajax which I did not know if this one is correct since I cannot retrieve the return

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#animaloption").change(function () {
         $('#animalfilter').val($("#animaloption").val());
         var animal= $('#animalfilter').val($("#animaloption").val());
          $.ajax({
           url: "ajax/test.php",
           type: "post",
           data: animal,
           success: function (response) {
               $("#kind").html(response);             
           }
          });
      });
   });
   ```

an input with **id = kind** does not show anything.

In my test.php

```
<?php
  $a = "SUCCESS";
  return $a;
 ?>
```

Kindly help guys.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you need to use `method: "POST"` instead of `type: "post"`. Adding `fail` callback may indicate some errors. I always refer this doc - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Lowercase `post` is fine, I think you will find it does not require `POST` to work. Let's see your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues going on here, I will note the areas of concern:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Not necessary, but better to use .on() here
    $("#animaloption").on('change',function() {
        // Use $(this) instead, grabs the selected value. No sense in
        // capturing the same event value when you have it in this event already
        var animal = $(this).val();
        // Assign value here to field
        $('#animalfilter').val(animal);
        // Start ajax
        $.ajax({
            // Make sure this is the correct path
            url: "ajax/test.php",
            type: "post",
            data: animal,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#kind").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**/ajax/test.php**

```
<?php
$a = "SUCCESS";
# You have to echo, not return
echo $a;
# Try print_r() for sure-fire results testing
print_r($_POST);
```

If these changes don't fix it, seeing your form html will be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to check if input textbox with id of **animalfilter** is changed and then query it using ajax

For 2.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#animalfilter").change(function () {
        $('#animalfilter').val($("#animaloption").val());
        // var animal= $('#animalfilter').val($("#animaloption").val()); //<-- i highly doubt you need this
        var animal= $('#animalfilter').val();                        //<-- rather this
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/test.php",
            type: "post",
            data: animal,
            success: function (response) {
                  $("#kind").html(response);             
            }
       });
   });
});
```